# Value of window.prompt not returning the proper "Length" property value

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I am a bit new to Javascript and I am trying to learn it. I am currently creating a piece of code where it prompts the user to enter their name in and it displays if it has 5 characters or more, less, or exactly. But it keeps displaying me that it is 5 characters even though it is more than 5. If anyone could help debug this for me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3school.org/1999/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Understanding Javascript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            language="javascript">
    username = prompt("Please enter your name");
    message = "Hello," + username + " Your name has ";
    nameLen = username.Length;
    if (nameLen > 5)
        message = message + "more than ";
    else if (nameLen < 5)
        message = message + "less than ";
    else
        message = message + "exactly ";
    message = message + " 5 characters";

    alert(message)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like a typo - you have `username.Length`, and it should be `username.length`.   Your variable can have any name that you want, but the `.length` should be all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line here:

```
nameLen = username.Length;
```

This line actually sets `nameLen` equal to `undefined`.

The way in which you set out your `if` statement,

```
if (nameLen > 5) { // undefined is not greater than 5

} else if (nameLen < 5) { // undefined is not less than 5

} else { // undefined is not equal to 5 either, but who cares? it's a broad else

}
```

Means that it will always go into the `else` clause.

In order to fix this problem, simply change `username.Length` to `username.length`. JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, so these kinds of errors may appear more often in the future if you're not careful.

Comment: Oh thank you for the tip. I didn't know that it was a case sensitive language.

Comment: @BenjaminNguyen No problem - definitely important to keep that in mind. In addition, I would suggest always using `{` and `}` - curly braces, when separating your `if/else` clauses. The previous answerer (who has now deleted his answer) misunderstood your code, simply because you did not have curly braces, so the inclusion of such is paramount.

Comment: it's absolutely case sensitive!  You should be able to check your developer console in the browser if you have JavaScript error reporting enabled and it would report problems such as this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `username.length` should fix it. Typo in the property name. This code looks like it works.

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3school.org/1999/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Understanding Javascript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                language="javascript">
        username = prompt("Please enter your name");
        message = "Hello, " + username + " Your name has ";
        nameLen = username.length;
        if (nameLen > 5)
            message = message + "more than ";
        else if (nameLen < 5)
            message = message + "less than ";
        else {
            message = message + "exactly ";
            }
        message = message + " 5 characters";
  
        alert(message)
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact syntax :

> nameLen = username.length;